# How to change value of all submit buttons onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to change value of button when I'm clicking on it. For example there is a button with value **Send**, when I am clicking I want button change value to **Loading...**. I need realise this for all **submit** buttons in document.

I have tried to use this code:

```
<script>
var button = $('[type="submit"]');
button.click(function(){
    button.attr('value','NEW');
});
</script>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var button = $('[type="submit"]');
button.click(function(event){
    // if you need jquery methods then:
    $(this).attr('value','NEW');
    // shortcut for setting value:
    $(this).val('NEW');
    // or simply
    this.value = "NEW";

    // you may want to stop further processing with:
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J625U/2/)

Comment: I want to use only this type of button `<input type="submit" value="Send">`

Comment: *if you need jquery methods then:*  it should be `$(this).val('new')`

Comment: When I'm clicking on `<input type="submit" value="Send">` it doesn't work.

Comment: Suggest op to use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @user3780736 it works, check jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try This code.

This will give you result.

```
$('[type="submit"]').each(function(){$(this).click(function(){$(this).val("NEW")})})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type=submit]").on('click', function(e){
        $(this).val('Loading ...');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/578an/)